# C# word spell check dialog, how to not open word

Tags: c#

I am using a word reference in c# and I need to know how to make it so office doesn't open when you use the spell check dialog, here is the code

```
private void metroButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

    int errors = 0;
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        app.Visible = false;

        // Setting these variables is comparable to passing null to the function.
        // This is necessary because the C# null cannot be passed by reference.
        object template = Missing.Value;
        object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
        object documentType = Missing.Value;
        object visible = true;

        Word._Document doc1 = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);
        doc1.Words.First.InsertBefore(richTextBox1.Text);
        Word.ProofreadingErrors spellErrorsColl = doc1.SpellingErrors;
        errors = spellErrorsColl.Count;

        object optional = Missing.Value;

        doc1.CheckSpelling(
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional,
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);

        object first = 0;
        object last = doc1.Characters.Count - 1;
        richTextBox1.Text = doc1.Range(ref first, ref last).Text;
    }
}
```

If you know how to help, please do

Comment: It is explicitly noted in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171830(v=office.11).aspx), "If the document or range contains errors, this method displays the Spelling and Grammar dialog box".  So use app.CheckSpelling() instead.